# Rotation from inertia tensor

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

How can I tell by looking at any inertia tensor that, it won't roll or pitch.

Imagine I have this inertia tensor:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\
   I_{yx} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\
   I_{zx} & I_{zy} & I_{zz} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there any symmetry that or any formula to calculate if it will produce any angular acceleration in roll and pitch only?

There is a big approach, I was asking if there is any short approach.

Comment: If there is no torque and the body is rigid, then, of course, you will have no angular acceleration. Perhaps you are thinking of a situation with a specific torque applied?

Comment: @Void actually what I was trying to know is - suppose there is a wight in stable position, now if i put a weight in one hand it will of course fall on a side... like that , can I know if there is such way to know from inertia tensor, if it is balanced or not, in a short way ??